# Convert from lowercase to uppercase all values in all character variables in dataframe

Tags: r, string, uppercase

I have a [mixed dataframe](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1791181/multcol.csv) of character and numeric variables.

```
city,hs_cd,sl_no,col_01,col_02,col_03
Austin,1,2,,46,Female
Austin,1,3,,32,Male
Austin,1,4,,27,Male
Austin,1,5,,20,Female
Austin,2,2,,42,Female
Austin,2,1,,52,Male
Austin,2,3,,25,Male
Austin,2,4,,22,Female
Austin,3,3,,30,Female
Austin,3,1,,65,Female
```

I want to convert all the lower-case characters in the dataframe to uppercase. Is there any way to do this in one shot without doing it repeatedly over each character-variable?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Starting with the following sample data :

```
df <- data.frame(v1=letters[1:5],v2=1:5,v3=letters[10:14],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  v1 v2 v3
1  a  1  j
2  b  2  k
3  c  3  l
4  d  4  m
5  e  5  n
```

You can use :

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(v) {
  if (is.character(v)) return(toupper(v))
  else return(v)
}))
```

Which gives :

```
  v1 v2 v3
1  A  1  J
2  B  2  K
3  C  3  L
4  D  4  M
5  E  5  N
```

Comment: I just found this works too: df = as.data.frame(sapply(df, toupper))

Answer (score 62):

From the `dplyr` package you can also use the `mutate_all()` function in combination with `toupper()`.  This will affect both character and factor classes.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate_all(df, funs=toupper)
```

Comment: For anybody looking at this from today onward, note that `mutate_each()` is depreciated; instead (assuming you wish to convert your entire `data.frame` to upper/lower), use `mutate_all()`.

Comment: 'mutate_at()' could be used to work with only one variable

Comment: this worked for me: df <- mutate_all(df,, funs(touper))

Comment: Make sure to use `mutate_all(df, .funs = toupper)` for proper syntax or you will receive an error. There should be a "." before the `funs` parameter.

Also, if you want want to stick to the `tidyverse` you can use the `stringr` `str_to_upper` rather than the `base` `toupper`.

Answer (score 13):

### dplyr >= 1.0.0

Scoped verbs that end in `_if`, `_at`, `_all` have been superseded by the use of [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) in `packageVersion("dplyr")` 1.0.0 or newer. To do this using `across`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), toupper))
```

- The first argument to `across` is which columns to transform using [tidyselect](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) syntax. The above will apply the function across all columns that are character.
- The second argument to `across` is the function to apply. In addition to named functions, this also supports a purrr-style lambda function/formula syntax: `~ toupper(.x)` or an anonymous function `function(x) toupper(x)` (or short hand in R > 4.1.0 `\(x) toupper(x)`) that make setting additional function arguments easy and clear.

### purrr

Alternatively, you can use the `modify_*` functions from the `purrr` package:

```r
library(purrr)

df %>%
  modify_if(is.character, toupper)
```

- The third argument to `modify_if` is the function to apply. In addition to named functions, this also supports a purrr-style lambda function/formula syntax: `~ toupper(.x)` or an anonymous function `function(x) toupper(x)` (or short hand in R > 4.1.0 `\(x) toupper(x)`) that make setting additional function arguments easy and clear.

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(city = c("Austin", "Austin", "Austin", "Austin", 
"Austin", "Austin", "Austin", "Austin", "Austin", "Austin"), 
    hs_cd = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), sl_no = c(2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L), col_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), col_02 = c(46L, 32L, 27L, 20L, 
    42L, 52L, 25L, 22L, 30L, 65L), col_03 = c("Female", "Male", 
    "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
    "Female")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 10):

It simple with apply function in R

```
f <- apply(f,2,toupper)
```

No need to check if the column is character or any other type.

Comment: Note that this converts numeric columns to characters and it also converts the data from data.frame to matrix.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to use a combination of `mutate_if()` and `str_to_upper()` function, both from the tidyverse package:

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_to_upper) -> df
```

This will convert all string variables in the data frame to upper case.
`str_to_lower()` do the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

A side comment here for those using any of these answers. Juba's answer is great, as it's very selective if your variables are either numeric or character strings. If however, you have a combination (e.g. a1, b1, a2, b2) etc. It will not convert the characters properly.

As @Trenton Hoffman notes,

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate_each(df, funs(toupper))
```

affects both character and factor classes and works for "mixed variables"; e.g. if your variable contains both a character and a numberic value (e.g. a1) both will be converted to a factor. Overall this isn't too much of a concern, but if you end up wanting match data.frames for example

```
df3 <- df1[df1$v1 %in% df2$v1,]
```

where df1 has been has been converted and df2 contains a non-converted data.frame
or similar, this may cause some problems. The work around is that you briefly have to run

```
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate_each(funs(toupper), v1)
#or
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate_each(df2, funs(toupper))
#and then
df3 <- df1[df1$v1 %in% df2$v1,]
```

If you work with genomic data, this is when knowing this can come in handy.

Comment: mutate_each has been deprecated - the suggestion from the latest version of R  is to use across()

Answer (score 2):

If you need to deal with data.frames that include factors you can use:

```
df = data.frame(v1=letters[1:5],v2=1:5,v3=letters[10:14],v4=as.factor(letters[1:5]),v5=runif(5),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df
    v1 v2 v3 v4        v5
    1  a  1  j  a 0.1774909
    2  b  2  k  b 0.4405019
    3  c  3  l  c 0.7042878
    4  d  4  m  d 0.8829965
    5  e  5  n  e 0.9702505


sapply(df,class)
         v1          v2          v3          v4          v5
"character"   "integer" "character"    "factor"   "numeric"
```

Use mutate_each_ to convert factors to character then convert all to uppercase

```
   upper_it = function(X){X %>% mutate_each_( funs(as.character(.)), names( .[sapply(., is.factor)] )) %>%
   mutate_each_( funs(toupper), names( .[sapply(., is.character)] ))}   # convert factor to character then uppercase
```

Gives

```
  upper_it(df)
      v1 v2 v3 v4
    1  A  1  J  A
    2  B  2  K  B
    3  C  3  L  C
    4  D  4  M  D
    5  E  5  N  E
```

While

```
sapply( upper_it(df),class)
         v1          v2          v3          v4          v5
"character"   "integer" "character" "character"   "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you just want to convert one particular row to uppercase, use the code below:

```
df[[1]] <- toupper(df[[1]])
```