# ignore case in frequency for factor variable in r

Tags: r, frequency

I am trying to get frequency of factors in one column using `table` but **I realized that some factors although identical letters but different in case i.e capital letter /small letters** as you can see in the attached figure. I checked the frequency of each factor using pivot table in excel (as in the screenshot below.
Here is my working dataset ([Link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ag2qagJCadbCgxpK0yBFgIeY51tI))
I used the foillowing code

```
table ( data$new.Article.Subspecialty)
```

I tried the following but it gave me error.
    table ( data$new.Article.Subspecialty,ignore.case=T)

> Error in table(data$Article.Subspecialty, ignore.case = T) :    all
>   arguments must have the same length

Anyway to solve this (may be capitalize them as in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516593/convert-from-lowercase-to-uppercase-all-values-in-all-character-variables-in-dat) ) but this is a column in my big dataset.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table` doesn't have `ignore.case` as argument.  we can convert to same case with `tolower` or `toupper` and then apply the `table`

```
table(tolower(data$new.Article.Subspecialty))
```

Comment: I also tried this that edited fixed the variable itself based on your comment `data$new.Article.Subspecialty<-tolower(data$new.Article.Subspecialty);
table(data$new.Article.Subspecialty)`

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Thank you for the comments.  Regarding your second comment, do you need any other fix

Comment: No. thanlks I am just sharing what I did and found it useful . Appreciate your follow-up